# How to get the value of an input box of the webbrowser control in WPF?

Tags: c#, html, wpf, browser

I added Microsoft.mshtml as a reference to my project and came this far:

```
        mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 document = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)webbrowser.Document;
        string username = document.all["username"].GetAttribute("value");
```

but the 2nd line doesn't work. It says

> *"error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type
>   'mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection'"*

when hovering over "all". How do I access the elements in all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var document = (IHTMLDocument3) webbrowser.Document;
var value =
    document.getElementsByName("username")
            .OfType<IHTMLElement>()
            .Select(element => element.getAttribute("value"))
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It works. May I ask actually does? The results of getElementsByName get wrapped into something I can do LINQ queries on and you use that to filter the result by type IHTMLElement and then select only the value Attribute and then get the first of the result? Is that right or is this also some COM IHTMLDocument3 Feature? Is it possible to do that with document.all as well or are there reasons that won't work or is not convenient in c# ?

Comment: Method `getElementsByName` returns `IHTMLElementCollection` which implements `IEnumerable` interface so we could use LINQ to iterate over it. To do this we should safely cast each element to `IHTMLElement`. `document.all` also returns `IHTMLElementCollection` which means you could handle it the same way as the method above.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for a couple of hours this solutions worked for me.

```
Dim document = DirectCast(MainBrowser.Document, IHTMLDocument3) 
Dim formName = document.getElementsByName(AppSettings("myFormName")).OfType(Of IHTMLElement)().Select(Function(element) element.getAttribute("name")).FirstOrDefault()
```