# how to get the input element by class using mshtml.IHTMLDocument2

Tags: c#, wpf, mshtml

I'm new in using mshtml package library from .NET and, as such, I'm struggling to read the input element rendered in WPF web browser control.

I have researched through the internet and stumbled on this link. [How to get the value of an input box of the webbrowser control in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835533/how-to-get-the-value-of-an-input-box-of-the-webbrowser-control-in-wpf)

But in my case, I want to read/get the input element by class, not by name attribute.  Unfortunately, I know that GetElementByClass is not an option in WebBrowser.Document

This is my code - When I tried to run the debugger, the code doesn't continue inside the foreach loop ):

```
private void browser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        IHTMLElementCollection elementCollection;
        IHTMLDocument3 dom = (IHTMLDocument3)browser.Document;
        elementCollection = dom.getElementsByTagName("input");

        foreach (HtmlElement item in elementCollection)
        {
            if (item.OuterHtml.Contains("input_search"))
            {
                //Do something else here...
            }
        }
    }
```

A screen capture of the DOM of the page
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does variable 'dom' holds? Have a look in it during debugging.

Comment: @Sumit, the variable dom holds the following data via the elementCollection variable can be seen here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B1S0vrR6A9T8YW1QNVB1eFEtdDA?usp=sharing

Comment: This one IHTMLDocument3 dom = (IHTMLDocument3)browser.Document;

Comment: @Sumit Oh, I have replaced the image file here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B1S0vrR6A9T8YW1QNVB1eFEtdDA for the dom variable data.  I have only screen captured the top most name and value pairs.  There's a lot of exception (as shown in the image), what could have caused?